# Video desired starting time syncing

Tags: java, android

I am new in Android Development. i have a video in my raw folder and i want to play it in different parts like 20-40 secs or 1:20-2.30 secs. The problem is in syncing of video time. lets assume my video start from 1:34 (which is 94 in int) secs. on api less than 23  it is working fine and plays video exactly at my desired time, but on api above than 23 it plays from 1:32 sec (92 in int). how to solve this problem ? Any help and suggestion would be appreciated. THANKS

```
case "Exer2":
        {
            mPlayBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mVideo.postDelayed(onExer2ForEverySecond,1000);
            Log.i(TAG,"Exer2 Case");
            mStartTime=94*1000;
            mVideo.seekTo(mStartTime);
            mVideo.start();
            break;
        }

Runnable onExer2ForEverySecond=new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        mVideo.postDelayed(onExer2ForEverySecond,1000);
        if(mVideo.isPlaying())
        {

            if(mVideo.getCurrentPosition()==153*1000){
                mVideo.pause();
            }
        }

    }
};
```

Comment: Do you use the same video file for both tests (api above and less 23) or different videos for different devices?

Comment: i was testing on the same video

Answer (score 0):

**Key-frame**

A video consists of frames (pictures) usually 30 frames per second. Frames can be two types:

- Key-frame, sync-frame or intra-frame
- Not key-frame

**Key-frames** contain a full picture, while **not key-frame** contain changes of the previous **key-frame**. So if you will look on any **not key-frame** you not will see a complete image just some part. **Not key-frame** have no sense without a **key-frame**.

A key-frame takes up more space and a not key-frame takes match less space. This algorithm provides an ability to reduce video file size.

The main points are:

- If a key-frame appears once per second it means tath 29 other frames are not key-frames in this second.
- The frequency of a key-frame in different videos can be different for example one video will have 1 key-frame per second and another video will have 1 key-frame per 3 seconds.

Here is [the Wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_frame) for more details.

**Seeking video**

[VideoView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView), what seems you are using, under a hood use [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer) [.seekTo()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#seekTo(long,%20int)) method. This method will seek your video to millisecond what you have set. But in case if in the video at this millisecond contains a not key-frame, **seekTo()** method will search to [a previous key-frame](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#SEEK_PREVIOUS_SYNC) (because a not key-frame has no sense for a user who watches your video).

Returning to a previous key-frame will reduce milliseconds that you have set in a seekTo() method. That is why your video plays from 1:32 sec not 1:34 (which is 94 in int) secs. And it totally not depends on Android API level.

**Solution**

Actually, there are no easy solutions what you can implement in your code, all depends on videos what you will use.

Videos should have a frequency of key-frames 1 per second or more often. In this case, you will seek your videos to the desired second without any problems.

In case if a frequency of key-frames less then 1 per second (for example 1 per 2 seconds), you will need to reconvert your videos to reach a key-frame frequency 1/second. Do it programmatically is not an easy task, so better prepare your videos in the Adobe Premier or any another video tool.